# Drupal 7 AJAX error when running batch with Internet Explorer

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I'm getting an AJAX error when running any batch with Internet Explorer 8, 9 and 10.

This error occures when I'm using "feeds" module, "views send" module or when I delete a user.

For example, when I try to send multiple mails with "views send" module, I get this error:

> "An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: >/batch?id=1613&op=doStatusText: OK ResponseText: ﻿﻿{"status":true,"percentage":"50","message":"Sent 1 of 2 messages.\u003Cbr /\u003E"}"

The first mail is sent, whereas the following mails are not.

I'm not getting this error with Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Interesting problem you've got there (gotta love IE...). Can't find anything remotely related on Google which might indicate this is a conflict with another custom/contrib module you have installed, or perhaps a server setup issue? Not sure how best to advise, but maybe you could get a list of contrib modules that you installed together and dump them into the question? Also if you have secure pages installed try disabling it temporarily, it can do strange things to batch ops sometimes